# Number of isolated singularities

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus

If $f:G\longrightarrow\mathbb{C}$ is analytic except for the isolated singularities and has infinitely many singularities, why then the singularities only can accumulate on boundary of $G$?

Which is an example of such $f$?

(I was reading the Residue Theorem and the hypothesis asks finitely isolated singularities, but later the author note this question and I could not answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, isolated singularities are **isolated**, so they can have no accumulation point in $G$. For an example where the singularities accumulate on the boundary, take for example
$$
f(z) = \frac{1}{\sin \frac1z}
$$
on $G = \{ z \in \mathbb{C} : |z-1| < 1 \}$, where $z=0$ is a limit point of isolated singularities of $f$.